# connecting more than one Lm35 sensor to ADC pins of Atmega32 micro-controller in Proteus software

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, proteus, lm335

[image]I am trying to simulate a heating system using an atmega32 microcontroller, 4 lm35 sensors, and Proteus software for circuit simulation. Unfortunately, whenever I run the simulation I encounter the error:"'Power Supply' (330mV) is outside the specified range (3.5V-30V)" which says that the sensors are not getting enough voltage to start working. This error pops up when I connect more than 1 lm35 sensor to the ADC pins of atmega32(port A). When there is only one sensor it works correctly. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the MCU pins are properly configured as analog inputs?

Comment: yes, PORTA is the only port in Atmega32 which can convert analog signals to digital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of digital ICs (MCUs, logic gates etc) in the ISIS library have hidden VCC/VDD pins. By default, they are not shown in the schematic but are designed to connect automatically to POWER terminal (the terminal with the up-arrow symbol). Yeah, it's 5VDC but it's not suitable for powering analog ICs like LM35.

Replace them with a "DC" source. You can find it under GENERATORS group to the left (the circle with a blue sine-wave symbol inside it). Place one, double-click on it and set the voltage to 5.

*Note that if you're planning to transfer this circuit to ARES for PCB design then it will be problematic because of that POWER terminal.*

Comment: I did that but the same error happened again!

Comment: I've Proteus 7 on my Lab PC and I tried a similar thing: If I don't connect LM35's supply pin then I get the same message (not error, just a message with exclamation icon) but the simulation still goes on. If I connect it to a POWER terminal or a DC supply then I get no messages. I think you should make sure that the sensors' power pins are connected to the supply. Don't put an individual POWER terminal or a DC source for each sensor, connect all the sensors' power pins to a single supply instead.

Answer (score -1):

Double click on every power supply symbol and add +5v, don't forget +.